# Implementing IDbSet in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and already implemented in my project.
I made some changes to make more testable, so I implement interface

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    internal MyEntities context;
    internal IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWithRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return dbSet.SqlQuery(query, parameters).ToList();
    }
    ...
}
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IGenericRepository<Employee> { }   
public class EmployeeRepository : GenericRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository { }
```

in UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
    private IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository
    {
        get { return employeeRepository ?? (employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository(context)); }
    }
}
```

Then I cannot access dbSet in `GetWithRawSql()` because I change to `IDbSet`. 
(1) How to solve this?

(2) Is there any better approach (without dbSet) to this code using the above approach as this is also failed because IDbSet

```
unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.dbSet.Select(c => new {    
    EmpID = c.EmployeeID,   
    FullName = (c.LastName + ", " + c.FirstName)
}).OrderBy(o => o.FullName);
```

Thanks.

Comment: See this:http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24550/repository-pattern-and-unit-of-work

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ thanks for the link, but still not helping

Answer (score 1):

i believe that this is a poor implementatin, here is the one im currently using:
this is going to be your IRepository

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
    void Add(T item);
    void Remove(T item);
    void Update(T item);
    void Attach(T item);
    IQueryable<T> All<TProperty>(params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] path);
    IQueryable<T> All(params string[] path);
    T Find(object id);
    T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] path);
    Task<T> FirstAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] path);
    T First<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] path);
    IQueryable<T> Where<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] path);
    IQueryable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] includes);
   }
```

often you need to attach entities to context so i added Attach method but if you want to keep entity framework attach Seperate (witch is not really needed) from regular IRepository you can define a new interface and called ISqlRepository and inherit from IRepository, creating two IRepository will just make it more complex since it dosnt make any problem in UnitTest. any way if you do want to seperate this is going to be your ISqlRespository:

```
 public interface ISqlRepository<T>: IRepository<T> where T:class, IEntity
 {
      void Update(T item);
      void Attach(T item);
 }
```

this is unitOfWork interface:

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        IRepository<T> Repistory { get; }
        IRepository<TEntity> GetTypeRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity;
        object GetContext();
        int Commit();
        Task<int> CommitAsync();
}
```

and finally concrete implementation (without ISqlRepository since i dont use that):

this is implementation of IRespository:

```
public class SqlRepository<T>: IRepository<T> where T: class, IEntity
{
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _objectSet;
    protected ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public SqlRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _objectSet = context.Set<T>();
        this._context = context;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _objectSet.Add(item);
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        _objectSet.Remove(item);
    }

    public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] path)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        if (path != null)
        {
            path.ForeEach(i => query = query.Include(i));
        }

        return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public T First<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] path)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        path.ForeEach(p => query = query.Include(p));
        return query.First(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Where<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] path)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        path.ForeEach(p => query = query.Include(p));
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        includes.ForeEach(i => query = query.Include(i));
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }


    public IQueryable<T> All<TProperty>(params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] path)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        if (path != null)
        {
            path.ForeEach(p => query.Include(p));
        }
        return query;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All(params string[] path)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        if (path != null)
        {
            path.ForeEach(p => query = query.Include(p));
        }
        return query;
    }

    public T Find(object id)
    {
        return _objectSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Attach(T item)
    {
        T old = _objectSet.Local.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id);
        if (old != null)
        {
            _context.Entry<T>(old).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
        _objectSet.Attach(item);
    }


    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> FirstAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] path)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet;
        if(path != null)
        {
            path.ForeEach(i => query = query.Include(i));
        }
        return query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }
}
```

this the unitOfWork:

```
 public class SqlUnitOfWork<T> : IUnitOfWork<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public SqlUnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public IRepository<T> Repistory
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlRepository<T>(_db);
        }
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Task<int> CommitAsync()
    {
        return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public object GetContext()
    {
        return this._db;
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetTypeRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        return new SqlRepository<TEntity>(_db);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but why it is a poor implementation?

Comment: there is alot i can say since o`v first learnt Repository and unitOfWork from the tutorial you`v linked and faced alot of problem. take a deeper look at what i wrote in my answer i think its pretty clear.